# How to detect Mockery BadMethodCallException reason in Laravel and fix it?

Tags: php, laravel, mockery

I was trying to add a new notification and new channel in a Laravel 9 application when faced an exception saying:

`Received Mockery_0_Illuminate_Notifications_ChannelManager::send(), but no expectations were specified`

To my surprise other notifications already existing in the project are also facing the same issue. Everything is OK and running smoothly on our production server and the mentioned exception only happens in local environment.

I tried to update Laravel version to 10 but the results was the same.
I tried both Linux (Manjaro) and Windows (Windows 10) computers and nothing changed.
I should add that both on our production server and my local development environment I use PHP 8.1.